# Get network printers

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, printers, network-printers

I need to detect the network printers on my PC. I tried this method:

```
PrintQueueCollection networkQueues;

using (var printServer = new PrintServer())
{
    var flags = new[] { EnumeratedPrintQueueTypes.Shared, EnumeratedPrintQueueTypes.Connections };
    networkQueues = printServer.GetPrintQueues(flags);
}
```

[image: result network queues]

But they are not detected. Yet I have two network printers, detectable with this code:

```
var printerNames = PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters;
```

[image: all my installed printers]

Comment: Perhaps you want `LocalPrintServer` not `PrintServer`

Comment: Tried with "var printServer = new LocalPrintServer()", but same result